# insecure_private_key の置き換えについて

Tags: security, vagrant, ssh

`vagrant`がバージョン1.7以降になってから
初回のbox作成・起動時に`insecure_private_key` を
置き換えていると説明されていますが、具体的に何がどうなっているのでしょうか。

質問の経緯は以下のとおりです。

現在`ubuntu 15.04`で`vagrant 1.7.2`を使っています。
以前、ホストOSに`windows7`を使っていた頃、
`vagrant`が1.7になってからのことですが、boxを新規作成させた後、
`teraterm`等からログインできなくなるという現象が起こり、
それについてはネットの情報を参考に`Vagrantfile`に

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

という1文を挿入することでさしあたりの問題は解決しました。

いくつかの説明を読んでいると、どうやら`vagrant`が1.7になってからの仕様変更で、
[vagrantの提供する共通公開鍵](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant.pub)を持つboxを使ったゲストOS作成時では
それに対応するホスト側の秘密鍵(`~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`)が
自動的に置き換えられてしまう……らしい……みたいなことになっていると
なんとなく理解していました。

ところが今日、OSを`ubuntu`に変えてから初めて、

```
vagrant init chef/centos-6.6
```

とした後に、`Vagrantfile`を全く編集しない状態でも

```
vagrant ssh
```

とすると、普通にログインできてしまいました。
これは以前、`windows7`で`vagrant 1.7`を使っていた時には
`teraterm`でエラーになっていたはずでした。

これはもしかして1.7.2では何らかのバグが治ったのだろうか？
くらいに考え、でも気になるので、試しに
`~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`と

```
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/
```

に置いてある、[vagrantという名前のファイル](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant)
（共通公開鍵に対応する秘密鍵のはず）
の中身を比較してみると、中身が全く同じです。

**ランダムに置き換えられた秘密鍵に変わるんじゃなかったのか？？**
と、これまでの理解か、確認の方法、またはその両方が間違っているらしいと
気が付いた次第。

元々公開鍵暗号の仕組みも、秘密鍵を持つ人だけが公開鍵を使って暗号を解ける、
くらいの理解しかなかったので、そもそもそれが間違いなのかもしれませんが、
結局、`vagrant` が初回のbox作成・起動時に`insecure_private_key`を
置き換えていると説明されているのは、具体的に何がどうなっているのでしょうか。

愚問かと思いますが、教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。
確かに現在の`vagrant`はゲストOSの初回起動時にホストOS側の鍵情報を自動で変更し、ゲストOSと暗号の再調整を行っています。
ただし、その置換後に使う秘密鍵ファイルの場所は`vagrant ssh-config`というコマンドを使わないと分からないようになっていました。

```
$ vagrant up
...
...
(ゲストOS起動中)
...
(ゲストOS起動後に以下を実行)
$ vagrant ssh-config
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2222
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile /home/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL
```

`IdentityFile /home/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key`の部分が置き換えられた秘密鍵ファイルです。
したがってこのファイルを指定して`ssh`コマンドを実行すると`vagrant ssh`としたときと全く同じ動作をします。

```
ssh -p 2222 -l vagrant -i /home/xxxx/.vagrant/machines/www/virtualbox/private_key 127.0.0.1
```