# NTEmacs で vagrant の中に tramp するには？

Tags: windows, emacs, vagrant

Windows 上で、以下のプログラムがインストールされています。

- NTEmacs 24.4
- Vagrant + VirtualBox

この環境で、 emacs 上から tramp で vagrant box の中に入りたいのですが、これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

---

追記@2016/09/23

今回の目的は Windows 上で linux の開発を行うことが目的でしたが、これをやるんではなく、仮想マシンに直接 PuTTY で接続してその中で emacs を実行するなどする方がいろいろやりやすことがわかりました。

Comment: [dougm/vagrant-tramp](https://github.com/dougm/vagrant-tramp)

Comment: @argus vagrant-tramp は、 `tramp-login-program` に、自前の bash スクリプトを利用する様子ですが、これが、自分の手元の環境だと `executable-find` できなくてバグりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

（私はVagrantを使ったことがないため、勘違いしている箇所があるかもしれません）

NTEmacs+Trampに必要なのは次の2点です

1. SSHクライアントをインストールする

   - [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)
   - [OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)

有名なWindows用SSHクライアントといえばこれでしょうか。インストールしてEmacsから呼び出せるようにPATHを通しておいてください。

2. SSHログイン用のサーバ情報を `~/.ssh/config` に書き込む

[vagrant ssh-config](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh_config.html) コマンドを使えばSSHログインに必要な情報を出力することができるそうです。コマンドプロンプトを開いて次のコマンドを実行してください。(`HOSTNAME` はログインするサーバ名です)

```
vagrant ssh-config --host HOSTNAME >> %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config
```

あとはEmacs から <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> でファイルを開くときに次の書式でログインすることができます。

```
/ssh:HOSTNAME:/path/to/file
```

<s>PuTTYをインストールした場合は書式内の`ssh`を`plink`に置き換えてください。</s>

---

**追記 (2016/01/14)**

[PuTTYのドキュメント](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.66/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-file)によると設定の保管はレジストリのみで~/.ssh/configファイルは今のところサポートしていないそうです。

代替案としてvagrantの秘密鍵ファイル`%USERPROFILE%/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`を利用して公開鍵認証方式でログインする方法はどうでしょうか。

1. puttygen.exe を使ってvagrantの秘密鍵ファイルからPuTTY用秘密鍵(*.PPK)と公開鍵を生成する
2. pageant.exe を起動して.PPKファイルを読みこませる
3. 公開鍵をサーバの ~/.ssh/authorized_keys に登録する
4. Emacsを起動してTramp経由でログインする

ログイン時の書式は少し冗長になります。ユーザ名やポート番号はそれぞれ置き換えてください。

```
/plink:USERNAME@HOSTNAME#PORT:/path/to/file
```

Comment: PuTTY ベースの方法を試してみていたんですが、 plink って `~/.ssh/config`の設定情報を読み込んでくれるものなのでしょうか。

Comment: できるものだと勘違いしてました…。代わりに別の方法を追記しておきました。

Comment: PuTTY の話ですが、 insecure_private_key をいじって、ssh の設定の面倒を見てくれるところまでが vagrant のやってくれることだと理解しています。なので、 3 は多分不要なのではないか、と考えています。

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY でひとまずログインできたので、その方法を記述します。 kosh さんの方法でも可能ですが、 insecure_private_key の管理は vagrant が行ってくれるものなので、 authorized_keys を自分で登録するのは、ちょっと違うかもと思い、試行錯誤した結果、次になりました。

1. puttygen.exe を使ってvagrantの秘密鍵ファイルからPuTTY用秘密鍵(*.PPK)と公開鍵を生成する。利用する秘密鍵にどれを使ったらいいかは、 [insecure_private_key の置き換えについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10987/754) 参照。
2. pageant.exe を起動して.PPKファイルを読みこませる
3. Emacsを起動してTramp経由でログインする

   (find-file "/plink:vagrant@localhost#2222:~")

ただ、記述して思いましたが、あまり手間は変わらなかったです。